# Compare two arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, compare

I have two arrays

```
double A[2][4] = {
    {9, 10, 11, 12.0},
    {13 14 15 16.3}
};

double B[2][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 16},
    {17, 18, 19, 20}
};
```

I want to see if some elements in both arrays are approximated.
Say if A[:,2:4] ~ B[:,2:4], I want the program to print the row number. Here is my approach:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        if (A[i][3] - B[k][3] < abs(0.5) && A[i][4] - B[k][4] < abs(0.5)) {  
            printf("row %d\n",k);
        } 
    }
}
```

But It does not work as I want.
Pls tell me what I have to do?
Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why the code for `B` won't compile? That would be because it's invalid C... you need to declare an array large enough to contain all elements.

Comment: Do you want to compare every row of `A` with every row of `B`?

Comment: Type of B is not consistent with its initializer

Comment: I have just re-modified the source code and the question for more clarity.

Comment: @palindrom I would like to compare just only 2 elements of each row (2nd and 3rd column) of A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple compilation issues in your program:

1. When declaring the array `A` you missed some commas:
   `{13 14 15 16.3}` -> `{13, 14, 15, 16.3}`
2. When declaring the array `B` you defined the size incorrectly:
   `double B[2][4]` -> `double B[5][4]`
3. You didn't declare `i` and `k` in your function
4. Your ranges are incorrect, `k < 4` should be the condition in the second loop
5. Your `abs` method will not work as the return value is an integer, not a double. Use `fabs` instead

When you fix all those, the program compiles and runs. The output is:

```
> ./main
row 3
```

Comment: But I need both: row 2 and row 3

Comment: I found out my mistakes

if (abs(A[i][3] - B[k][3]) < 0.5 && abs(A[i][4] - B[k][4]) < 0.5)
-->
if (abs(A[i][2] - B[k][2]) < 0.5 && abs(A[i][3] - B[k][3]) < 0.5)

Answer (score 3):

Various problems.

---

**`int abs(int)`**

Below are the same as `abs()` is an `int` function:

```
A[i][3] - B[k][3] < abs(0.5) 
A[i][3] - B[k][3] < 0
```

OP likely wanted to use the floating point funciton `fabs()` in a different way.

```
fabs(A[i][3] - B[k][3]) < 0.5
```

**Range**

`k` runs out of range.

```
// for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
```